# WPF Plugin not recognized

Tags: c#, wpf, plugins, expression-blend

I am writing on an application which works with plugins.
In a main-program i load all plugins by looking for the plugin interface in the assembly.

All my plugins (VB.NET v4.0 and C# v4.0) based on WPF will be recognized, except one. This plugin is using ResourceDictionaries, lots of Templates and subdirectories.
This plugin is written in Visual Studio 2010 and Expression Blend 4 in C# based on WPF 4.0.

Its very odd, because the plugin is recognized in the main program. But after a few tests and builds the main program stops recognizing the plugin.

I made a backup of the working plugin and the plugin, which is not recognized anymore.
The csproj files are pretty much the same and also the settings.

I can't find a solution and google also does'nt know very much about this problem.

If found some infos, that XAML code effects the assembly, so other programs can't recognize it. But there are no specific infos about that and also no solution.

Does anyone know that problem and much better - does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Can you please post some code that shows how you are loading the plugins?

Comment: I found out what the problem actually was. The plugin threw an exception and the pluginmanager ignored the plugin. But now i face a new problem: If i try to instantiate my main window, the debugger throw an exception, that the System.Windows.Interactivity.dll was not found.

The Debugger says: 
(XamlParseException)
The file or assembly "System.Windows.Interactivity, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" or a dependency cannot be found. The system cannot find the file.

If i run the application as standalone (The plugin have a "Debug.xaml", which loads the plugin in a window mode), all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Relating to your additional comment (XamlParseException):

Do you referenced the System.Windows.Interactivity.dll in your Main-Project (which is loading the plugin) and in your Plugin-Project?

Comment: I found the problem. The main program is startet in my root folder. All plugins are located in root\plugins.
The problem was, that i had the System.Windows.Interactivity.dll in the plugins folder and not in the root.

My collegue solved the problem, because he wrote the main program.
But thanks for your help :)